# Docker file shared between mac and linux?

Tags: linux, macos, docker

I am new to Docker. I am using a mac to do the development. And I will deploy the web app onto Linux. Can I use the same docker file between two different systems? I don't think so though...

Comment: Yes. Its just a set of instructions. If your instructions are OS specific, that's where you'll get into trouble

Comment: Oh, I see. So if nodejs and postgres are consistent on both OS. Then it will work. So I'd better keep using things which are consistent on both OS. Am I right?

Comment: All versions of Docker on the Mac actually use a Linux VM, so you're actually building and running Linux images and containers.  You should be able to `docker push` an image you built on a Mac to a registry and `docker run` it on a Linux host.

Comment: Cool. I will have a try. Thanks for your help. @David and gregory